# Why is my for loop not moving my list elements from -1000px left to 20px left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a sidebar for a website I am working on and I am trying to learn how to move list elements individually in javascript using a for loop. I tried implementing the list into an array and having each one move when the sidebar button is clicked. However I cannot get them to move. Can someone take a look and give me tips, thank you.

```js
const sidebarBut = document.querySelector('.sideBarBut');
let openClose = false;
let animationInProgress = false;
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.projects');
sidebarBut.addEventListener('click', animate);

function animate(){
    if (animationInProgress) return;
    animationInProgress = true;
    const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    
    if (openClose !== true) {
        sidebar.classList.remove('animate2');
        sidebar.classList.add('animate1');
        document.querySelector('.animate1').style.animationPlayState = "running";
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            list[i].style.left = '20px';
        }
        openClose = true;
    } else {
        sidebar.classList.remove('animate1');
        sidebar.classList.add('animate2');
        document.querySelector('.animate2').style.animationPlayState = "running";
        openClose = false;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        animationInProgress = false;
    }, 600);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

/*--------Header--------*/

#header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.header1 {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.aboutButton {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
}

.homeButton {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.projectButton {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
}

.aboutButton:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.homeButton:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.projectButton:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.githubButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: -223.8px;
    left: 83.3%;
    transform: scale(0.0675);
}

.linkedinButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: -230px;
    left: 80%;
    transform: scale(0.065);
}

.instagramButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: -230px;
    left: 76.65%;
    transform: scale(0.065);
}

.githubButton:hover {
    transform: scale(0.075);
}

.linkedinButton:hover {
    transform: scale(0.075);
}

.instagramButton:hover {
    transform: scale(0.075);
}

.header2 {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black, white, black);
}

/*--------Sidebar--------*/

.sideBarBut {
    transform: scale(0.065);
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 742.5px;
    left: -235px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sideBarBut:hover {
    filter: brightness(80%);
}

.sidebarTitle {
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: -50px; /*7px*/
    left: 95px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 4px;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}

@keyframes titleDrop {
    0% {
        width: 0;
        border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    }
    100% {
        width: 250px;
        border-right: 2px solid white;
    }
}

#sidebar {
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}

.animate1 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-name: sidebarOpen;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animate2 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-name: sidebarClosed;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes sidebarOpen {
    0% {
        width: 0;
        border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    }
    100% {
        width: 250px;
        border-right: 2px solid white;
    }
}

@keyframes sidebarClosed {
    0% {
        width: 250px;
        border-right: 2px solid white;
    }

    100% {
        width: 0;
        border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    }
}

.projectLinks {
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: -1000px; /*20px*/
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.projects {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.projects:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/projectsSheet.css">
        <title>Projects Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="header1">
                <div class="mainBut">
                    <a href="index.html" class="aboutButton">About Me</a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="homeButton">Home</a>
                    <a href="projects.html" class="projectButton">Projects</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sideBut">
                    <a href="https://github.com/aidanbh16" target="_blank"><img src="img/github.512x499.png" alt="github" class="githubButton"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/aidan-holton/" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin-app-white-icon.png" alt="linkedin" class="linkedinButton"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/holton_aidan/" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram-white-icon.png" alt="instagram" class="instagramButton"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header2"></div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div id="sidebar" class="animate1">
                <button type="button" class="sideBarBut"><img src="img/sidebar.png"></button>
                <span class="sidebarTitle">Projects</span>
                <ul class="projectLinks">
                    <li><a class="projects" href="projects/Tic Tac Toe Project copy/index.html">Tic Tac Toe Project</a></li>
                    <li><a class="projects" href="projects/color changer proj/index.html">Color Changer Project</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have looked upon your code and found out that the project class is missing the `position` property.

Please specify the `position` property to `relative` or `absolute` to manipulate left, right, top or bottom.

Your required Code:-

```js
.projects {
position: relative; //could be relative or absolute
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: sans-serif;
line-height: 30px;
}
```