# Why isn't the text coming out together and why are they overlapped?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my side bar text to come out when the sidebar button is clicked one at a time with a slight delay. However only one of the text comes out and the second comes out only after i close the sidebar. There is also the issue of the text overlapping. I have tried a lot of methods and cant get it to stop overlapping.

```js
const sidebarBut = document.querySelector('.sideBarBut');
let openClose = false;
let animationInProgress = false;
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.projects');
sidebarBut.addEventListener('click', animate);

function animate(){
    if (animationInProgress) return;
    animationInProgress = true;
    const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    
    if (openClose !== true) {
        sidebar.classList.remove('animate2');
        sidebar.classList.add('animate1');
        document.querySelector('.animate1').style.animationPlayState = "running";
        list.forEach((link, index) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                link.classList.remove('animate4');
                link.classList.add('animate3');
                document.querySelector('.animate3').style.animationPlayState = "running";
              }, 100);
        });
        openClose = true;
    } else {
        sidebar.classList.remove('animate1');
        sidebar.classList.add('animate2');
        document.querySelector('.animate2').style.animationPlayState = "running";
        list.forEach((link, index) => {
            link.classList.remove('animate3')
            link.classList.add('animate4');
            document.querySelector('.animate4').style.animationPlayState = "running";
        });
        openClose = false;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        animationInProgress = false;
    }, 600);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

/*--------Header--------*/

#header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.header1 {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

.aboutButton {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
}

.homeButton {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.projectButton {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
}

.aboutButton:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.homeButton:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.projectButton:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.githubButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: -223.8px;
    left: 83.3%;
    transform: scale(0.0675);
}

.linkedinButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: -230px;
    left: 80%;
    transform: scale(0.065);
}

.instagramButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: -230px;
    left: 76.65%;
    transform: scale(0.065);
}

.githubButton:hover {
    transform: scale(0.075);
}

.linkedinButton:hover {
    transform: scale(0.075);
}

.instagramButton:hover {
    transform: scale(0.075);
}

.header2 {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black, white, black);
}

/*--------Sidebar--------*/

.sideBarBut {
    transform: scale(0.065);
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 742.5px;
    left: -235px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sideBarBut:hover {
    filter: brightness(80%);
}

.sidebarTitle {
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: -50px; /*7px*/
    left: 95px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 4px;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}

@keyframes titleDrop {
    0% {
        width: 0;
        border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    }
    100% {
        width: 250px;
        border-right: 2px solid white;
    }
}

#sidebar {
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}

.animate1 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-name: sidebarOpen;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animate2 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-name: sidebarClosed;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes sidebarOpen {
    0% {
        width: 0;
        border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    }
    100% {
        width: 250px;
        border-right: 2px solid white;
    }
}

@keyframes sidebarClosed {
    0% {
        width: 250px;
        border-right: 2px solid white;
    }

    100% {
        width: 0;
        border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    }
}

.projectLinks {
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.projects {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    left: -1000px;
    top: 60px;
}

.projects:hover {
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.animate3 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-name: sidebarLinks1;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animate4 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-name: sidebarLinks2;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes sidebarLinks1 {
    0% {
        left: -500px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 35px;
    }
}

@keyframes sidebarLinks2 {
    0% {
        left: 35px;
    }
    100% {
        left: -500px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/projectsSheet.css">
        <title>Projects Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="header1">
                <div class="mainBut">
                    <a href="index.html" class="aboutButton">About Me</a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="homeButton">Home</a>
                    <a href="projects.html" class="projectButton">Projects</a>
               </div>
                <div class="sideBut">
                    <a href="https://github.com/aidanbh16" target="_blank"><img src="img/github.512x499.png" alt="github" class="githubButton"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/aidan-holton/" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin-app-white-icon.png" alt="linkedin" class="linkedinButton"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/holton_aidan/" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram-white-icon.png" alt="instagram" class="instagramButton"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header2"></div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div id="sidebar" class="animate1">
                <button type="button" class="sideBarBut"><img src="img/sidebar.png"></button>
                <span class="sidebarTitle">Projects</span>
                <ul class="projectLinks">
                    <li><a class="projects" href="projects/Tic Tac Toe Project copy/index.html">Tic Tac Toe Project</a></li>
                    <li><a class="projects" href="projects/color changer proj/index.html">Color Changer Project</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no need to make a second post for the same code 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78061502/why-is-my-for-loop-not-moving-my-list-elements-from-1000px-left-to-20px-left

Comment: no one answered that question and I also updated it a good bit.

Comment: The `setTimeout()` calls in the `list.forEach()` loop all have the same timeout, so all the animations will start at the same time. If you want them separated, use something like `100 * index` as the timeout.

Comment: Would i put that in setTimeout(function(100* index) ?

Answer (score 0):

To apply an animation for all links inside a sidebar `document.querySelector('.animate3')` and `document.querySelector('.animate4')` were changed to `link` so that every item of `forEach()` can be used instead of the same first element returned by the `document.querySelector()` in all iterations.

A slight delay between the link animations was accomplished by changing the timeout (as @Barmar mentioned) from `100` to `100 + (index * 400)`.

To avoid text overlapping the `position` of `.projects` was changed to `relative` and the `top` property was removed. A space above the links was added with `margin-top` in `.projectLinks`.

```js
const sidebarBut = document.querySelector('.sideBarBut');
let openClose = false;
let animationInProgress = false;
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.projects');
sidebarBut.addEventListener('click', animate);

function animate() {
  if (animationInProgress) return;
  animationInProgress = true;
  const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

  if (!openClose) {
    sidebar.classList.remove('animate2');
    sidebar.classList.add('animate1');
    document.querySelector('.animate1').style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    list.forEach((link, index) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        link.classList.remove('animate4');
        link.classList.add('animate3');
        link.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
      }, 100 + (index * 400));
    });
    openClose = true;
  } else {
    sidebar.classList.remove('animate1');
    sidebar.classList.add('animate2');
    document.querySelector('.animate2').style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    list.forEach((link, index) => {
      link.classList.remove('animate3')
      link.classList.add('animate4');
      link.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    });
    openClose = false;
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    animationInProgress = false;
  }, 600);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}


/*--------Header--------*/

#header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.header1 {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.aboutButton {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
}

.homeButton {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.projectButton {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
}

.aboutButton:hover {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.homeButton:hover {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.projectButton:hover {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.githubButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: -223.8px;
  left: 83.3%;
  transform: scale(0.0675);
}

.linkedinButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: -230px;
  left: 80%;
  transform: scale(0.065);
}

.instagramButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: -230px;
  left: 76.65%;
  transform: scale(0.065);
}

.githubButton:hover {
  transform: scale(0.075);
}

.linkedinButton:hover {
  transform: scale(0.075);
}

.instagramButton:hover {
  transform: scale(0.075);
}

.header2 {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, white, black);
}


/*--------Sidebar--------*/

.sideBarBut {
  transform: scale(0.065);
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 742.5px;
  left: -235px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sideBarBut:hover {
  filter: brightness(80%);
}

.sidebarTitle {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  /*7px*/
  left: 95px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 4px;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}

@keyframes titleDrop {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  }
  100% {
    width: 250px;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
  }
}

#sidebar {
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}

.animate1 {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-name: sidebarOpen;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animate2 {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-name: sidebarClosed;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes sidebarOpen {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  }
  100% {
    width: 250px;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
  }
}

@keyframes sidebarClosed {
  0% {
    width: 250px;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  }
}

.projectLinks {
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.projects {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  left: -1000px;
}

.projects:hover {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.animate3 {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-name: sidebarLinks1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animate4 {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-name: sidebarLinks2;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes sidebarLinks1 {
  0% {
    left: -500px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 35px;
  }
}

@keyframes sidebarLinks2 {
  0% {
    left: 35px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -500px;
  }
}


/* ============ */
/* SNIPPET DEMONSTRATION STYLES */
/* CAN BE REMOVED */
.sideBarBut {
  transform: none;
  background-color: white;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.sideBarBut::after {
  content: ">";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
}
.sideBarBut img {
  display: none;
}
/* ============ */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/projectsSheet.css">
  <title>Projects Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <div class="header1">
      <div class="mainBut">
        <a href="index.html" class="aboutButton">About Me</a>
        <a href="index.html" class="homeButton">Home</a>
        <a href="projects.html" class="projectButton">Projects</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sideBut">
        <a href="https://github.com/aidanbh16" target="_blank"><img src="img/github.512x499.png" alt="github" class="githubButton"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/aidan-holton/" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin-app-white-icon.png" alt="linkedin" class="linkedinButton"></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/holton_aidan/" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram-white-icon.png" alt="instagram" class="instagramButton"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header2"></div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div id="sidebar" class="animate1">
      <button type="button" class="sideBarBut"><img src="img/sidebar.png"></button>
      <span class="sidebarTitle">Projects</span>
      <ul class="projectLinks">
        <li><a class="projects" href="projects/Tic Tac Toe Project copy/index.html">Tic Tac Toe Project</a></li>
        <li><a class="projects" href="projects/color changer proj/index.html">Color Changer Project</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I couldn't see the button so I've added the temporary styles for `.sideBarBut` to make sure it is visible in the snippet (feel free to remove them).

Also, an expression `openClose !== true` was changed to `!openClose` - there is no need to make an explicit check if you plan to assign it only with boolean values.